# 2 submit buttons on same form with MVC 3. Only one submit button is working in IE 9

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-9

I gave submit buttons a name, and then inspected the submitted value in the controller method. When I click on register button it is not triggering action method, which is on server. This is working fine with chrome and IE 10 and above it is not working in IE9.

```
<% Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post); %>
<input type="submit" name="PostValue" value="UploadImage" />
<input type="submit" name="PostValue" value="Register" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced on that.
But there is a solution to this problem if you don't want to use submit buttons with the same name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostNews", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" name="submit.Publish" value="Publish News" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit.Save" value="Save News" />
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, ActionName("PostNews"), ActionRequired("submit.Publish")]
    public ActionResult PublishNews()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View(...);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("PostNews"), ActionRequired("submit.Save")]
    public ActionResult SaveNews()
    {
        return View(...); 
    }
}

public class ActionRequiredAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    private readonly string _submitButtonName;
    public ActionRequiredAttribute(string submitButtonName)
    {
        _submitButtonName = submitButtonName;
    }
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var actionRequired = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[_submitButtonName];
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionRequired);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in my case i can't use 2 actionresult methods. I have to use same action for both the buttons.